# Who discovered the expansion for factorial as a successive difference of integers?

Tags: mathematics, discoveries

Who discovered the following [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591350/expressing-a-factorial-as-difference-of-powers-sum-r-0n-binomnr-1)

> $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}(-1)^r(n-r)^n=n!$$

Comment: I'm willing to bet it was 'discovered' more than once.

Answer (score 3):

I firstly encountered this identity while working with related sums. Within this [question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856676/summation-problem-involving-odd-numbers-and-binomial-coefficients-prove-sum), asked by myself, the user *Robert Z* refered to the particular case you are asking for as [Tepper's Identity](http://www.ssmrmh.ro/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/TEPPERS-IDENTITY.pdf). In order to be precise Tepper's Identity is a more general result given by

> $$n!~=~\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk (a-k)^n,a\in\mathbb R$$

The aforementioned proof of Tepper's Identity was given by *Ravi Prakash* and was posted on the $2$nd of January $2018$ on the official website of the Romanian Mathematical Magazine which can be found [here](http://www.ssmrmh.ro/2018/01/02/teppers-identity/). Later on it reappeared within [RMM - Famous Inequalities Marathon 1 - 100](http://www.ssmrmh.ro/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/RMM-FAMOUS-INEQUALITIES-MARATHON-1-100.compressed.pdf) as problem $97$. There are various proofs avaible nowadays, for instance [*Another Proof of Tepper's Identity*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2687866?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by *F. J. Papp* published in the *Mathematics Magazine* Vol. $45$, No. $3$ $($May, $1972)$, pp. $119-121$ and [*A Proof of Tepper’s identity*](https://nttuan.org/2007/10/10/tepper/) by *Nguyen Trung Tuan* posted on the $10$th of October $2007$.

Concerning the origin it seems like all sources are dating back to an arcticle called [*A Factorial Conjecture*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2687939?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by *Myron Tepper* published in the *Mathematics Magazine*
Vol. $38$, No. $5$ $($Nov., $1965)$, pp. $303-304$ $($the index to this volume can be found [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.1965.11975666?journalCode=umma20)$)$ proposing the identity, perhaps, for the first time.